# What should I do when I see an off-topic example in documentation?

Tags: support, documentation

I started using documentation and in the [very first topic I viewed](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/saying-hello-from-javascript#t=201607211633229244688) there are already off-topic example as to "debugging in javascript" instead of printing stuff to "say hello".
I'm sure we will see this often, what shuold we do?

Comment: Click the flag icon on the example?

Comment: Yes, but there no "off-topic" flag

Comment: I would use "not an example", since it's not an example of the topic at hand, but that's me.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Oh, I see. So it is an example but not an example of the topic so it's not a valid example... Not sure if it should have it's own flag though, because "not an example" also fits a valid piece of documentation that should not be in the examples section.